# For each $\phi$ show that exists $\psi$ in 3CNF such that $\phi$ is satisfiable if only and only $\psi$ is staisfable.

Tags: logic

For each $\phi$ show that exists $\psi$ in 3CNF such that  $\phi$ is satisfiable if only and only $\psi$ is staisfable.

Can you help me solve it ? I am starting at logic and everything seems to be undoable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove such things you have to do a structural induction on $\psi$.

Thus if you want to prove that for all formula $\psi$ the property $P(\psi)$ hold you show that:

- Base case: $P(\psi)$ hold when $\psi$ is a preposition, or the negation of a preposition.
- Induction step: Assume that $P(\psi_1)$ and $P(\psi_2)$ hold. Show that $P(\neg \psi_1)$ and $P(\psi_1 \circ\psi_2)$ hold for every connector $\circ$ that can compose your formula.

To do your proof, I would first show that I can transform any formula into an equivalent formula in negation normal form (formula only composed of proposition, negation of preposition and the connectors $\vee$ and $\wedge$). This proof is done by structural induction.

Then I would show that I can convert any formula in negation normal form into a CNF formula. Again by structural induction.

Finally I would show that any formula in CNF can be converted in an equivalent 3CNF formula. This last proof is done thanks to a nice trick that allow to separate a disjunction into 3 smaller disjunction by adding new variables.

If you still have trouble, or if something is unclear please ask.